# handling 2 depending subscriptions? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a component with this code

```
this.service().subscribe((result) => { this.service2(result).subscribe((result2) => //other code }}
```

I'm applying good practices in Angular and seems this is not a good approach for this kind of code. But not sure how to improve this.

any suggestion?

Comment: take a look at [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `switchMap` operator:

```js
this.service.getSomething().pipe(
    switchMap(result1 => this.service.getSomething2())
)
```